# StreamWriter - Difference between "\" and "/"

Tags: c#, streamwriter

What is the difference between the `\` and the `/` when doing streamwriter?

e.g.

**Example 1:**

```
Streamwriter sw = new Streamwriter("/test folder/Output/test.txt");
```

and

**Example 2:**

```
Streamwriter sw = new Streamwriter(@"\test folder\Output\test.txt");
```

I see you need the `@` symbol in the front on the second example too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987950/using-or-for-folder-paths-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference because .NET recognizes both [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx) and [the other](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar.aspx) in paths.

However, since `\` has special meaning when appearing inside a string literal (it is the beginning of an escape sequence) the second example uses [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) syntax. It could have used `\\` in place of `\` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `@` only improves readability, a string starting with `@` will simply have all its `\`'s replaced by `\\` during compile time and `\` added where needed.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid path separator characters in .NET.

IOW, it is exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The `\` is generally used in Windows to separate directories, however I think it does accept `/` in most circumstances as well.

The `\` also needs to be escaped, hence the `@` symbol. You could also use `\\` to escape this character as well.

Answer (score 1):

Because with `\` start escape characters. For example `"\""` will print `"`. If you want to use `\` as a character either you need to add `@` in front of string or use `\\`. As you see it has nothing to do with path-s both form are valid for `streamwriter`.