# Passing image from C# to R

Tags: c#, r

I want to pass image from C# to R. I'm uploading my image using FileUpload and storing it into a folder "images".When i'm passing images location to R it gives me error. So,can you guys suggest me any alternate way to solve this error.Following are my code.

```
// Get Filename from fileupload control

string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);             

engine.Evaluate("imgPath<-'~/images/filename'"); //error in this line

// Read the image into a raster array

engine.Evaluate("img<-readJPEG(imgPath, native = FALSE)");

// convert the array to a data.frame 

engine.Evaluate("mystring<-as.data.frame(img)");

engine.Evaluate("myfreqs <- mystring / sum(mystring)");

// vectorize

engine.Evaluate("abc <- as.data.frame(myfreqs)[,2]");

// create input matrices

engine.Evaluate(@"a <- matrix(c(abc), nrow=4)");
```

Comment: Are you sure your '~/Image...' syntax applies here? Know this only from ASP.NET. Even there you have to map the 'logical' path to the 'physical' to use a file from code.

Comment: i'm not sure about the syntax. When i'm passing the exact location then code works perfectly.

Comment: Then it´s clear: '~/...' is wrong. Then it should be: engine.Evaluate("img<-'" + yourpath + '");

Answer (score 1):

And here as answer:

```
 engine.Evaluate("imgPath<-'" + filename + "'");
```

filename should be the complete path

Comment: ya it's working but i'm getting this error:The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

Comment: what is the Content of maybeFullPath? Does this file (including complete path) exists?

Answer (score 0):

PREFACE: I know nothing of C#. However, your situation is familiar. Why not call a shell command or a R process from C#? I have done this numerous times between Python and R. Consider abstracting the two languages by using R's automated executable [RScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151212/how-can-i-read-command-line-parameters-from-an-r-script) and pass image name as argument from C# using [Process.Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands) or a new [Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output) object?

**C#** Script

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
string args = @"C\Path\To\RScript.R" + " " + filename;

// SHELL COMMAND
// (RScript path can be shortened if using environment variable)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Path\To\RScript.exe", args);

// PROCESS OBJECT
var proc = new Process {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = @"C:\Path\To\RScript.exe",
        Arguments = @"C\Path\To\RScript.R" + " " + filename,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
```

**R** Script

```
options(echo=TRUE)
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

# pass argument into string 
imgPath <- args[1]

img <- readJPEG(imgPath, native = FALSE)

# convert the array to a data.frame 
mystring <- as.data.frame(img)    
myfreqs <- mystring / sum(mystring)

# vectorize
abc <- as.data.frame(myfreqs)[,2]

# create input matrices
a <- matrix(c(abc), nrow=4)
```

Comment: every thing worked fine but i'm getting "No overload for method 'Start' takes 3 arguments" error at  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.1/bin/i386/RScript.exe", "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.1/bin/i386/RScript.R", filename);

Comment: See edit. I had to concatenate the R file string with your image filename for two arguments. Be sure to only use one type: shell command or process object. Also, is your script really called RScript.R and located in same folder as RScript.exe? You can name your script anything and place it anywhere. My post used placeholders.

Comment: Ya, I placed my RScript.R file and RScript.exe in same folder

Comment: No bro i'm still getting "No overload for method 'Start' takes 3 arguments" error .

Comment: See update. Backslashes might need [escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987950/using-or-for-folder-paths-in-c-sharp).